# Java won't read Node.js server

Tags: java, android, node.js

So I am trying to get an Android application read from a Node.js Server. Here is the code to the Node server

```
exports.init = function (app) {
    app.get('/Ping', ping);
}

function ping(req, res, next) {
    res.end('Response');
}
```

-Next edit-

So I changed it to Async and here is the code I did for that

```
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
try {
    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://localhost/ping"); //localhost in place of actual ip
    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet, localContext);
    String result = "";

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

    String line = null;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        result += line + "\n";
        pageResult = result;
    }
} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

// TODO Auto-generated method stub
return pageResult;
}
```

But when I run it here is the html it returns (note that I will parse out the html later)

```
<HTML>
    <HEAD>
        <TITLE>401 Unauthorized</TITLE>
    </HEAD>
    <BODY BGCOLOR="#CC9999">
        <H4>401 Unauthorized</H4>
            Authorization required. please note that the default username is "root" in all newer releases
    </BODY>
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try replacing

```
URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
```

with

```
HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
```

and also add

```
urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
```

Also, you should be closing the input stream in a finally clause in case an exception is thrown

Edit:

First, edit your question with the stack trace, not the answer :)

Second, ok, you are getting a NetworkOnMainThreadException. That means you have to run an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) and do that stuff in the doInBackground method of AsyncTask.

Comment: Still having problems. I did what you said but now I'm getting the error "android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException"

Comment: @Cciamlazy Same error? Maybe the request method should be POST?considering the URL is called login

Comment: Still got the same error. It has to be something with the "http://" protocol because when I take it off it doesn't crash the application. When it does have http it crashes the app.

Comment: I switched to AsyncTask but now I am getting something about authorization required. Check my edit.

Comment: @Cciamlazy You're missing the Authorization header in your request. If you set up the server you should be able do turn it off though (I've never done node.js so I have no idea how to do that).

Comment: There is nothing about an authorization header in the environment setup. I'll try a few things from the client end

Comment: I assume that if you try now with http://www.google.com it does work right? The error you are getting is some sort of authorization that the server requires and you are not sending from the client.

Comment: The problem is solved. I realized now that my port forwarding was messed up all along. Thanks for your time and effort. You really did help me out with the async stuff. That fixed it. Again, thank you